# TypeError: 'Section' object is not callable

Tags: python

I'm trying to testing python program. I don't have enough knowledge about python module. When I run the program I got such as error **server=myconf.getoption('server') TypeError: 'Section' object is not callable** and this is piece of program I'm trying to run

```
import sys
from zabbix_api import ZabbixAPI
import simpleconfigparser

#print(sys.argv)
key=sys.argv[1]
triggerDict=sys.argv[2]
try:
    debugStatus=sys.argv[3]
except:
    debugStatus=0

authfile = 'zabbix-api-auth.conf'

myconf = simpleconfigparser.simpleconfigparser()
print myconf.read(authfile)
server=myconf.getoption('server')
username=myconf.getoption('username')
password=myconf.getoption('password')
```

How should I do?

Comment: Please show the full error message and traceback.

Comment: **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "original_ack.py", line 17, in <module>
    server=myconf.getoption('server')
TypeError: 'Section' object is not callable** it's what I get when running the program.

Comment: Please show the content of zabbix-api-auth.conf

Answer (score 0):

A sample of - "how to use simpleconfigparser"

from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SimpleConfigParser/

if your ini file includes the following:

```
[app]
debug = yes
```

You can use it using:

```
from simpleconfigparser import simpleconfigparser

config = simpleconfigparser()
config.read('read.ini')

print(config.app.debug)
print(config.app.getboolean('debug'))
print(config['app']['debug'])
```